# Zend_Json_Server vs JSON-RPC spec

Tags: zend-framework, json-rpc

The ZF implementation of the JSON-RPC 2.0 protocol only allows error codes:

```
const ERROR_PARSE           = -32768;
const ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST = -32600;
const ERROR_INVALID_METHOD  = -32601;
const ERROR_INVALID_PARAMS  = -32602;
const ERROR_INTERNAL        = -32603;
const ERROR_OTHER           = -32000;
```

plus, range(-32099, -32000)

These are defined in the JSON-RPC spec as pre-defined and/or reserved. At least this is what get out of the spec:

> **The error codes from and including -32768 to -32000 are reserved for pre-defined errors. Any code within this range, but not defined explicitly below is reserved for future use.** The error codes are nearly the same as those suggested for XML-RPC at the following url: http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/specs/rfc.fault_codes.php
>
> code  message meaning
>   -32700  Parse error Invalid JSON was received by the server.
>   An error occurred on the server while parsing the JSON text.
>   -32600  Invalid Request The JSON sent is not a valid Request object.
>   -32601  Method not found    The method does not exist / is not available.
>   -32602  Invalid params  Invalid method parameter(s).
>   -32603  Internal error  Internal JSON-RPC error.
>   -32000 to -32099    Server error    Reserved for implementation-defined server-errors.
>
> **The remainder of the space is available for application defined errors.**

Nowhere does it say that you cannot, for example use -100 or 100. Am I missing something?

Somewhere I think that "server error" and "application error" have been confused by ZF as the same thing, while when reading the sourcefourge link above, clearly the authors of the protocol had something different in mind, allowing the application developers A LOT of space:

> In addition, the range -32099 .. -32000, inclusive is reserved for implementation defined server errors. Server errors which do not cleanly map to a specific error defined by this spec should be assigned to a number in this range. This leaves the remainder of the space available for application defined errors.

Comment: Anyone? I even created a ticket but all I got was a comment by O'Phinney that doesn't address the issue: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11991?focusedCommentId=49518#comment-49518

Answer (score 0):

I use the JSON-RPC component of ZF for a few projects. It works pretty well - but I would hardly consider it an exemplar of the JSON-RPC spec. As far as I know, only a couple clients out there actually test their implementations against Zend_Json_Server, so it's hardly a widely adopted implementation. At one point, I actually had to patch Zend_Json_Server to make it work with one client, as it was not following the spec properly (that's since been fixed).

So basically what I'm saying is "good point, you're probably right."  If it itches enough, just [fork zf2](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) and submit a pull request with a better implementation of the spec - much easier to get positive / negative feedback when you're looking at a diff.

If they accept it, submit a patch for zf1 to merge in downstream.

Comment: We just overrode Zend_Json_Server::fault() and Zend_Json_Server which solved the problem, at least for us.

I created a ticket to report the problem, if noone can be bothered to take a decent look at the issue then so be it. I am not going to waste more of my time by attaching a patch that'll never get looked at.

Comment: FWIW, pull requests to zf2 always get looked at.